# Calculate the following for a smooth function...

Tags: calculus

For a smooth function f(r) where r = |ṟ| and ṟ = xi̱ + yj̱ + zḵ is the radius-vector, calculate ∇f(r) x ṟ

I tried calculating the curl for this question, but I'm told that's not right. I know that ∇f(r) is the gradient, but I don't know how to work out the gradient of this particular function. Someone please help

Comment: Can the chain rule help?

Comment: Well how would I use it? This is where I'm stuck

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Visit following link for MathJax tutorial https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to show formally that ∇f(r) = f'(r)ṟ.  This is reasonable since the level sets of f are spheres ṟ=constant, and ∇f should point in a direction normal to them.

Can you take it from here?